# php7 and php7.1 with homebrew in OSX

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

since the late upgrade of homebrew i started getting these warning in the terminal even though the libraries exist and the config point to the correct path

```
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/opt/php70-apcu/apcu.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php70-apcu/apcu.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_signal_globals
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php70-apcu/apcu.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/opt/php70-apcu/apcu.so in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/opt/php70-apcu/apcu.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php70-apcu/apcu.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_signal_globals
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php70-apcu/apcu.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/opt/php70-apcu/apcu.so in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/opt/php70-intl/intl.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php70-intl/intl.so, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.59.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php70-intl/intl.so
  Reason: image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/opt/php70-intl/intl.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php70-intl/intl.so, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.59.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php70-intl/intl.so
  Reason: image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.0
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-apcu.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-igbinary.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-intl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-memcached.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-oauth.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini
```

when executing which php

```
/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/bin/php
```

and here is the result of brew list

```
brew list                                  ✔  10956  12:18:48
apr         libffi          openssl@1.1     php@5.6
apr-util        libmemcached        pcre            php@7.0
aspell          libpng          php55           php@7.1
autoconf        libpq           php55-intl      pkg-config
automake        libtool         php55-mcrypt        pv
composer        libxml2         php56           python
dnsmasq         libyaml         php56-intl      python@2
freetds         libzip          php56-mcrypt        readline
freetype        m4          php56-pcntl     ruby
gdbm            makedepend      php70           sqlite
gettext         mcrypt          php70-apcu      tmux
glib            memcached       php70-igbinary      tree
gmp         mhash           php70-intl      unixodbc
gnu-sed         n98-magerun     php70-mcrypt        webp
heroku          ncdu            php70-memcached     xz
icu4c           nginx           php70-oauth     zsh
jpeg            node            php70-opcache       zsh-syntax-highlighting
jq          oniguruma       php70-xdebug
libevent        openssl         php71
```

here is the output for brew doctor

```
brew doctor                       ✔  10981  12:38:48
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in the App Store.


Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5m-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3-config

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/node/ares.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares_build.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares_rules.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/des_old.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dso.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/krb5_asn.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/kssl.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pqueue.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl23.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui_compat.h
  /usr/local/include/node/pthread-fixes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-experimental.h

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  python@2
  heroku
  python
  php55

Warning: Your Xcode (9.2) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 9.4 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.


Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
  /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain.backup
  /usr/local/bin/hyperkit.backup
  /usr/local/bin/notary.backup
  /usr/local/bin/vpnkit.backup
```

any help on how to fix these warnings is appreciated

Comment: What is the output of `brew doctor` ?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni i added the output for brew doctor

Comment: Try to remove all these warnings and see if your problem is still there.

Comment: I did remove the warnings but still getting the same issue  @OrtomalaLokni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking how to solve this issue, you have to delete the php and related libraries and install again as homebrew/php tap became deprecated and all of the libraries used to install became part of homebrew/core.

so by default you will php7.2 installed when you do `$ brew install php` but you can you install specific version manually like php@7.0. if you need xdebug you can install with pecl install xdebug and add the path in your php.ini